# ag-Grid key handler on empty grid

Tags: angular, filter, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-Grid's `onKeyPress` and `onKeyDown` event handlers to set the `quickFilter` text in an input outside the grid.

When the user types a value that does not exist, the grid will have no rows and `onKey*` events won't happen anymore. How can I make it possible to catch the i.e. backspace key in this case to update the filter?

I will not accept a solution with attaching event handlers to document/window or using overlays.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use (change) instead of onKey*? and then backspace will trigger the function.

Comment: There is no change handler mentioned in ag-grid documentation.

Comment: :| :| it's not dependant on ag-grid. you have an input for the quick search that triggers the function!

Comment: you misunderstood: I am not typing into the input box - the focus is on ag-grid, using its event handlers to update the input filter box.